# Ember.js Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'addSite'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I followed the ember official guide when implementing my application and I get this error.
Nothing handled the event 'addSite' when issuing action from `{{view Ember.TextFieldplaceholder="Insert new site name"
      valueBinding="newName" action="addSite"}}`

My code index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sites">
<ul>
    {{#each site in controller itemController="site"}}
    <li>
        {{#linkTo 'sites.site' site}} {{site.siteName}} {{/linkTo}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
<div>
    {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Insert new site name"
      valueBinding="newName" action="addSite"}}
</div>


</script>
```

Script:

```
 WebApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('sites', { path: '/' } , function() {
        this.route('site', { path: ':site_id' })
    });
});

WebApp.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return WebApp.Site.find();
    }
});

WebApp.SitesContoller = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

addSite: function() {
    var newName = this.get('newName');
    var site = WebApp.Site.createRecord({
        siteName: newName
    });

    //Clear text field
    this.set('newName','');

    ////Save the new model
    site.save();

}



 });


WebApp.Site = DS.Model.extend({
id: DS.attr('integer'),       
siteName : DS.attr('string'), 
secretKey: DS.attr('string'), 
publicKey: DS.attr('string'), 
userIdentification : DS.attr('string') 

 });
```

Comment: "when issuing action from view" -> what do you mean by this ? Cant get that properly

Comment: @Selva-G: It is written in the code: `{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Insert new site name"
      valueBinding="newName" action="addSite"}}` When I press enter after inserting value to the textfield view I get error that addSite cannot be found.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uxojek/27/edit

Comment: Can you produce a jsbin for debugging

Comment: Well it is the first time I'm using this jsbin, My code is not working there http://jsbin.com/esibiv/1/edit,

Comment: Your working bin http://jsbin.com/axaqix/2/edit

Comment: Thanks good to know that all I was missing is the letter `R` in controller :(